# Problem when mounting usb

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I have an 8GB kingston Data Traveler that I found in an old box. lsusb sees the device as 64GB, and pmount gives this error:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

So, I tried fdisk. I can see it through fdisk, and I have tried deleting and adding a partion, nothing works, I just get that error.

When I use mount, I get this:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

When I use dmesg | tail, I get this:

```
[ 1313.321482] XFS (sdc1): Invalid superblock magic number
[ 1313.323979] XFS (sdc1): Invalid superblock magic number
[ 1313.331146] omfs: Invalid superblock (c0b60fc0)
[ 1313.333486] omfs: Invalid superblock (c0b60fc0)
[ 1372.581076] UDF-fs: warning (device sdc1): udf_fill_super: No partition found (2)
[ 1372.587708] UDF-fs: warning (device sdc1): udf_fill_super: No partition found (2)
[ 1515.334346]  sdc: sdc1
[ 1515.341876]  sdc: sdc1
[ 1519.335909] UDF-fs: warning (device sdc1): udf_fill_super: No partition found (2)
[ 1519.342673] UDF-fs: warning (device sdc1): udf_fill_super: No partition found (2)
```

Update: here is the output of sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdc-

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdc                                                      
└─sdc1 ntfs         4E63105748D002C1
```

here is the output of blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/sdc1 :

```
ntfs
```

and the output of sudo file -Ls /dev/sdc1

```
/dev/sdc1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 62, heads 242, hidden sectors 2048, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 62, sectors 15357951, $MFT start cluster 4, $MFTMirror start cluster 959871, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 04e63105748d002c1; contains Microsoft Windows XP/VISTA bootloader BOOTMGR
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Did you specify the filesystem type? Please run [filesystem info commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53371/54675) for the drive (using `sudo`) and paste the output into your question.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdc` (or as whatever device the drive is mounted)?

Comment: I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

If you need to format the drive, try to install `gparted` and try to rewrite the partition table use `gparted`

Comment: It does not work. Still not opening in ubuntu.